# Threshold timing per operation using the mvc mini profiler

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

This is the scenario I am facing: I am using MiniProfiler to profile some operations. But it lacks a particular functionality that I will have to use. There is a Settings file MiniProfiler that can let me do some configurations like what to consider for profiling and what not, what to think as slow and what not, etc. But these are global settings and apply to all operations being profiled. What I need is to be able to say something like this:

```
using (mvcminiprofiler.Step("OperationName", 1200)
{
    //some C# code 
}
```

This argument '1200' signifies that this operation is expected to take 1200 ms and do not save it's results to the database if it takes anything less than or equal to 1200 ms. But if it takes more than 1200 ms then save this response time to the data base. So I am basically talking about per operation threshold values.

I am willing to write a wrapper around the MiniProfiler for this but I am not willing to change the mini profiler source code. Actually we have already built a little framework around the mini profiler but we would not like to change its source code. But merely extend it's functionality in some ways.

Comment: This is tricky, you would need to flow this info into the IStorage some way, will ask Jarrod to have a look

Comment: Please do :) It makes sense because some operations that we want to profile and are not affecting the site in real time can have some large amount of time. So it makes sense to have operation level threshold timings apart from global thresholds. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of an override on `.Step()`, what about `.StepIf("Operation", 1200)` instead?

Comment: Would make sense too. Anything that lets us have operation level threshold :)

Comment: @JarrodDixon - Do we have any update on this?

Comment: I'm going to be doing some major work on MiniProfiler over the Christmas holiday, so I'll try and get this in.

Comment: @JarrodDixon - Hey Jarrod. Do we have any updates? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added the following new extension methods to MiniProfiler, available in [nuget 3.0.10-beta5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/3.0.10-beta5) and higher:

1. `MiniProfiler.StepIf(string name decimal minSaveMs, bool includeChildren = false)`
2. `MiniProfiler.CustomTimingIf(string category, string commandString, deciml minSaveMs, string executeType = null)`

You should be able to use these to do *exactly* what you are looking to do. In your case, you would use code like this:

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.StepIf("Operation Name", 1200)) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

You can use the `includeChildren` (defaults to false) to set whether or not to use the time recorded in child profiles when determining whether or not to save this `CustomTiming`.

More info in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/34).